# String Comparison - Object with String

Tags: c#

Take a look at this guys:

Output from my Immediate Window in VisualStudio.

```
"15" == x.Documents.Attributes["key"]
false
x.Documents.Attributes["key"]
"15"
```

Why false when both value are equal????

Attributes is a `Dictionary<string, object>`... nothing special.

I dont get it. I thought == knows how to handle strings even when with object.ToString().

What am I missing guys? Help me out on this one.

Comment: Try doing a .ToString() on the x.DocumentFile.Attributes["key"]. you are trying to compare objects, not the values. the object value is not the same as a string.

Comment: Because your attribute is an object, it is doing the object Equals which just checks memory addresses. If you know it is a string, you can cast to string before applying equality. Alternatively, use `.Equals`

Comment: What **exactly** is in the attribute? i.e. what does `x.DocumentFile.Attributes["key"].GetType().Name` produce?

Comment: I thought == on object already calls ToString()

Comment: @devhedgehog This is not true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53k8ybth.aspx

Comment: Now I know it too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comparing objects, (as is your case) it is normally better to use the Equals method rather than the == operator as is virtual so will call the correct implementation.

For your code:

```
x.Documents.Attributes["key"].Equals("15");
```

Should return true

EDIT: this only holds if your type is actually a string. If you want to check if the string representation of your object matches the other string representation, you should do as others have said and do:

```
x.Documents.Attributes["key"].ToString() == "15";
```

That said, I wouldn't recomend it. If the object doesn't have a `ToString()`, all you will check is that they are the same type (`Object`s implementation of `ToString()`). At this point, it depends on what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 4):

Because the value is only known as `object`, `==` is actually a reference equality check here. To perform a `string` test, the compiler needs to know that it is a `string`:

```
"15" == (string)x.Documents.Attributes["key"]
```

This is because operators like `==` are *overloaded*, not *overridden* - they are not polymorphic.

If the values are not all strings, then this is safer:

```
"15" == x.Documents.Attributes["key"] as string
```

because the `as` will return `null` if the returned value is not actually a `string` (and `==` is fine against `null` values here).

Comment: But aren't the references the same due to string interning?

Comment: @TimSchmelter that depends on where the strings came from; a string loaded from a database, or a file, or via string manipulation will not be interned. Only the literal `"15"` is guaranteed to be interned here.

Comment: another well thought out and documented answer, just what this question needs +1

Comment: Will Equal do the same?

Comment: @devhedgehog `Equals` is a polymorphic method, so it will work appropriately **assuming** the value on the left hand side (the target) is not `null` (contrast operators, where either operand can usually be `null`). Alternatively, the static `Equals("15", blah)` will work correctly for either or both operands `null`, including polymorphism

Answer (score 2):

The answer is rather simple: You are getting a key, which is of type `Object` and you are comparing it to a `string`. Try calling `ToString()` on the key that you get and you'll get the right comparison and thus a `true`.

Comment: That is why I am asking the question. I thought ToString is being called automatically.

Comment: @devhedgehog No, toString() isn't called automatically and this is a good thing.

Comment: (Explanation of @DavidArno's statement) Because sometimes you want to check if you have the exacty same KEY rather than checking if the key you have is of the exact same VALUE as the one you're comparing to.

Answer (score 0):

First line: `x.Documents.Attributes["key"]`

Second line: `x.DocumentFile.Attributes["key"]`

See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

you should use equals and type cast to string

```
"15".equals( 
    (string) x.Documents.Attributes["key"])
    false
    x.Documents.Attributes["key"]
    "15"
```

Answer (score 0):

Marc Gravell answer is absolutely correct, just to add, here an example:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {
        "key",
        string.Format("{0}", "hello") // this to avoid interning string
    }
};
Console.WriteLine(dic["key"] == "hello"); // false
Console.WriteLine((string)dic["key"] == "hello"); // true
```